# Center region on userLocation in MKMapView

Tags: objective-c, ios, location, mkmapview, userlocation

I'm confused. I have an MKMapView, and in the viewDidLoad method I do:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    mainDelegate = (PublicArtOmahaAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]; 

    XMLController  *myXMLController = [[XMLController alloc] init]; 
    [myXMLController parse];
    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    [self gotoLocation];

    // add annotations to map
    [self.mapView addAnnotations:mainDelegate.mapAnnotations];
    [myXMLController release];
}
```

[self gotoLocation] calls:

```
- (void)gotoLocation
{
    MKCoordinateRegion newRegion;

    CLLocation *userLocation = mapView.userLocation.location;
    float latitude = userLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    float longitude = userLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    newRegion.center.latitude = latitude;
    newRegion.center.longitude = longitude;

    [self.mapView setRegion:newRegion animated:YES];
}
```

So I thought this should center the map on the user's location when the mapView loads and I was also planning on implementing a button on the screen that would manually call gotoLocation again to update the user's location when they want.

But... when I run the app on a device it loads the map centered in a patch of ocean west of Africa which is apparently lat and long 0,0. What I thought was strange was that when I zoomed back to my real location, it had correctly placed my location as an annotation. So I guess there's something wrong with how I'm setting the user location in the gotoLocation? Anyone notice what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`MKUserLocation` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKUserLocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> ### location
>
> The current location of the device. (read-only)
>
> `@property (readonly, nonatomic) CLLocation *location`
>
> **Discussion**
>
> This property contains nil if the map view is not currently showing the user location or if the user’s location has not yet been determined.

It takes a few seconds for the MKMapView (or CLLocationManager) to get a fix on the user's location, and it may take a couple of tries to get a relatively accurate fix. Your best bet is probably to create a `CLLocationManager` object, assign it a delegate, and then zoom the map when the `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` method fires.

Comment: Or use the map view's own `mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:` delegate method.

Comment: Ok, it looks like I'm going to have to do one of those two things, but I don't understand what is happening with the code I have now. Apparently when I first zoom the screen it shows the wrong location because it has not found me yet, but when I pan over to my real location, it has put an annotation there. So when I hit a button to "find me", calling the same gotoLocation method, shouldn't it have the correct location to work with? It gets lat 37.33 and long 0 for every time I call the method after the original zoom in the simulator, or some other place in northeastern africa on a device.

Comment: Scratch that, I think the issue may have been with the CLLocation because I rewrote the gotoLocation method with a CLLocationCoordinate2D and it worked much better. I ended up implementing Anna's mapView:didUpdateUserLocation: method, but many thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `span` for the region too. Set it to some arbitary value, like `latitudeDelta = 0.01` (and the same for `latitudeDelta`).

Also, call `gotoLocation` from inside `– locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` (if you're using a location manager). That way you'll only call it when you have a valid user location.